# I want to replace a string with repeating char characters

Tags: java, regex, string

Given regex I want to replace that part of string with multiple "." character based on its size.

I tried something like this:

```
  s =  s.replaceAll(matcher.group(1),"." * matcher.group(1).length() );
```

but the "." * length gives an error any way I can fix that.

Comment: [Use `repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) to repeat the string.

Comment: Can you re-word your question, your explanation is kind of confusing. Are you trying to replace a specific word with `'.'` based on the original word's length?

Comment: ya essentially replace all the characters word that matched with "."

Comment: @kotatsuyaki What util do I have to import to use repeat it doesn't seem to work

Comment: im guessing cause in using java8 it won't work @kotatsuyaki?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use a formal pattern matcher here:

```java
String input = "Peas porridge hot, peas porridge cold";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\bpeas\\b");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while(m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(buffer, m.group().replaceAll(".", "."));
}
m.appendTail(buffer);

System.out.println(buffer.toString());
// .... porridge hot, .... porridge cold
```

The above logic is to match each occurrence of `peas` (case insensitive).  For each match, we pause and splice on a replacement which is the match (`peas`), with every character being replaced by dot.

Comment: m.appendReplacement(buffer, m.group()).replaceAll(".", ".")); this line is error because the second part isnt a string

Comment: @KKir Sorry, typo, I have corrected it.

Comment: what if group you want is m.group(1)

Comment: I don't have any context here, but using `m.group(1)` would only make sense if there were a capture group in the regex pattern being used.

Comment: thats what i want